# Annotatate a plot by inserting the function value on top of local maxima (spikes)

Tags: octave

I have been plotting frequencies of a signal in respect to time. In the plot the function values show some prominent spikes. I want to chose a few such spikes that are the highest among the others by inserting a small circle on top of such spikes in addition to the value of the function, i.e. the frequency or insert a rectangle above those few spikes and insert the value of the frequency. I tried first to find the maximum of all the frequencies, retrieve both the time point and the frequency, annotate this value with an arrow, then delete this frequency and start again the loop by looking for the maximum. Unfortunately, It did not work. One would not see any annotation in the plot.

```
for j=1:5
    [y,t] = max(copy_SignalCORR);
    messageToDisplay = num2str(y)
    annotation('textarrow', [t,t],[y,y-0.1], 'String', messageToDisplay)
    copy_SignalCORR([t]) = []
endfor
```

I am using Octave, installed recently. Can you propose some code that will be able to provide the annotation that I need ? Many thanks.

Comment: without seeing your data and running tests, it's possible you aren't getting the data points you want.  have you tried looking at the `findpeaks` function?  it seems from the help description that it might do what you want without using a loop for generating the data to annotate

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation of `annotation` (emphasis mine):

```
[...] You can select the type of annotation and then set its
position using either X and Y coordinates for line-based
annotations or a position vector POS for others.  In either case,
coordinates are interpreted using the "units" property of the
annotation object.  The default is "normalized", which means the
lower left hand corner of the figure has coordinates '[0 0]' and
the upper right hand corner '[1 1]'.
```

In other words, the `annotation` function is for annotating figure windows, in a manner which is agnostic of its contents. In other words, you specify 'window' coordinates, not 'graph' coordinates. Chances are your t and y are outside of the [0,1] range, meaning your annotation is being plotted "outside" the visible constraints of the window.

In your case, it would probably be more appropriate to use `text` together with `quiver` instead, which are functions for placing text and arrows respectively, using 'graph' coordinates.

Alternatively, if this process doesn't need to be fully automatic, you can use gtext / ginput to do this graphically first and get the required coordinates, and then simply make sure that the figure is produced in a reproducible manner afterwards.

---

Other possible problems with this code:

- Read the documentation for how `max` works (type `help max` in your octave terminal). You don't specify the nature of the copy_SignalCORR array, but I'm assuming whatever `max` is doing to that array is unlikely to be what you wanted it to do.
- You are modifying the iterable that you are iterating over in your loop. In general this is a bad idea, as it can lead to problems, so it's worth paying attention to what problems it could cause in this code. Again, the exact nature of the variables here is unknown from your question, but, e.g., if `copy_SignallCORR` is a 1D array and you're relying on `t` as an index, then deleting elements will mean that the indices are no longer compatible with the original array. Alternatively, if it's a 2D array, then `copy_SignalCORR([t])` is performing 'linear indexing' rather than 'row indexing', so you're probably not deleting what you think you're deleting.

Comment: Many thanks. Now I am confused concerning the code I provided for at least retrieving the coordinates of the points I need. Is there some other why to find, let's say the 5 highest peaks of the graph. Base on these I guess I might use the text command.

Comment: In general the logic of your approach isn't bad. I'm just saying, the specific code as written is making me think you're probably not doing what you think you're doing, hence I'm encouraging you to read the documentation of the functions you're using carefully to ensure you are calling it in the way that you intent. But as far as what this code is _actually_ doing is concerned, that really does depend on what the `t`, `y`, and `copy_SignalCORR` variables are, I'm afraid, (particularly what are their dimensions), so no point speculating about hypotheticals.